# Centos 5 how to allow users to connect to GNOME like in windows we have RDP

Tags: linux, gnome, centos

Does anyone can help me with any freeware software for Centos 5, users wants to connect to Centos 5 GUI GNOME from Windows machine.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Maneesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc). There is a [how-to](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) at the CentOS website for setting up a server.

Comment: This will only give me the command line access to all the users. Is there anyway I can get the actual GUI for all the users as in windows ??

Comment: @maneeshshetty VNC gives GUI access, you have to connect to the VNC server with a VNC client. The client can run on Linux or on Windows.